# Mac OS X: from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode for opencv-python barcode reader failes

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, qr-code, zbar

I am working on a `Mac OSX 10.13.6` and trying to build a barcode reader using `python3`. Unfortunately, I can not even import the decode module in the `pyzbar` package.  I have tried installing `zbar`, `libzbar0`, `zbarlight`, etc. and all attempts fail

Here are my successful installations

```
    $ pip3 install pyzbar
    Requirement already satisfied: pyzbar in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.8)
    $ pip3 install opencv-python
    Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.1.1.26)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.2)
```

Here is the failure message when I try to use my successfully installed `pyzbar` package to import a `decode` function despite the face that I know pyzbar has a decode function:

```
    >>> from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .wrapper import (
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 143, in <module>
        c_uint_p,    # minor
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
        return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
        libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", line 65, in load
        raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library')
    ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

When I tried to install `zbar`, this is what occurred:

```
    $ pip3 install zbar
    Collecting zbar
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/54/cc5819efc9ee7e34b60b41e1d2d4753b6dd0c26a41c9a552611f66aa106e/zbar-0.10.tar.bz2
    Building wheels for collected packages: zbar
      Building wheel for zbar (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-z0xoqwir --python-tag cp37
           cwd: /private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/
      Complete output (13 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'zbar' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/zbarmodule.o
      In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:
      ./zbarmodule.h:26:10: fatal error: 'zbar.h' file not found
      #include <zbar.h>
               ^~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for zbar
      Running setup.py clean for zbar
    Failed to build zbar
    Installing collected packages: zbar
        Running setup.py install for zbar ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-record-5zw82lo9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
             cwd: /private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/
        Complete output (13 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'zbar' extension
        creating build
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/zbarmodule.o
        In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:
        ./zbarmodule.h:26:10: fatal error: 'zbar.h' file not found
        #include <zbar.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~
        1 error generated.
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-install-rhbz3vss/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/74/01qhmy3s3qg_fwctkdf6mrvh0000gn/T/pip-record-5zw82lo9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

So then went to https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ and read that "The zbar DLLs are included with the Windows Python wheels. On other operating systems, you will need to install the zbar shared library." The site then gives an option to use `brew install zbar` or `pip install pyzbar`.

Because I do not want to install `homebrew`, I used `pip install pyzbar`.

It did not help. Any advice on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, sudo apt-get install zbar-tools